# Window Size when sender is faster than the receiver

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

I am maintaining an application that uses cyclic executive for application tasks and additional, low priority task for receiving files over FTP that can run after all other task finished processing in the current frame. This causes the receive task not to run at all for X ms, than it has 50-X ms to do all the recv calls.

I noticed that when setting the window size of the data socket (SO_RCVBUF) to a large number 25000, the throughput to the FTP server was lower than when setting it to 512.

Reading a little bit, it turns out that with TCP sockets, if the receiver is slower than the transmitter, large buffer size is adverse.

> To achieve maximum throughput, it is critical to use optimal TCP socket buffer sizes for the link you are using. If the buffers are too small, the TCP congestion window will never open up fully, so the sender will be throttled. **If the buffers are too large, the sender can overrun the receiver, which will cause the receiver to drop packets and the TCP congestion window to shut down. This is more likely to happen if the sending host is faster than the receiving host**. An overly large window on the sending side is not a big problem as long as you have excess memory.

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2005/11/17/tcp_tuning.html

This is very counter-intuitive for me. I do not understand how larger buffer can cause any harm, it is supposed to help the slower receiver to handle the data before slowdown is occurring.

Comment: See that this way: You've one lion (the receiver) and 500 Kg of fresh meat (the data). If you (the sender) throw the whole 500 Kg of meat to the lion jail (receiver buffer) at the same time, most of it will get rot (discarded/dropped) before the lion consumes it. Better to store (buffer) that meat in your freezer (sender buffer), and feed the lion every day, gradually.

Comment: @threadp If my buffer is large enough to hold the whole 500kg of data, why would it be dropped or discarded?

Comment: Don't take that analogy too strictly (it's not an example that covers all the cases... just a simple analogy). But answering your question: very large buffers are usually bad. It makes no sense to let the buffers grow indefinitely if the consumer rate is slower than the sender rate, no matter where the bottleneck is (usually it is the bandwidth, but it can be elsewhere): At some point the buffer will be full, or if it is large enough to hold stuff indefinitely, packets will start to be discarded due to timeouts (and other stuff, but keeping it plain simple... i think this explains why).

Comment: Since received, buffered data are to be acknowledged not by the application, but by the operating system's TCP implementation, packets won't _be discarded due to timeouts_. I can only think of lost packets as a reason for a large SO_RCVBUF lowering throughput, because then more data could be retransmitted. Does packet loss occur on that connection?